# php passing an object back from a class function

Tags: php, class

I have a set of PHP functions that I want to move into a new class. One of the functions is using &$obj in an argument to modify the original object:

```
function process_new_place_names(&$obj)
```

any changes made to $obj in this function are passed back to the script.

Question is, can I do this inside a PHP class too? Also, what is the terminology of this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can absolutely do this inside of classes.  It's known as [passing by reference.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Further reading:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Answer (score 2):

As SomeKittens says, this is perfectly possible inside a class. However, if `$obj` is itself an instance of a class, and all you need to do is modify its member variables (known as *mutating* the object) then there's no need to pass it by reference.

For example, the following code will output `baz`;

```
class Foo
{
    public $bar;
}

function process_new_place_names($obj)
{
    $obj->bar = 'baz';
}

$obj = new Foo();
$obj->bar = 'bar';
process_new_place_names($obj);
echo $obj->bar;
```

Pass-by-reference is only necessary when you want to change the value of the variable itself; for example, re-assigning the object reference:

```
function process_new_place_names(&$obj)
{
    $obj = new Foo();
    $obj->bar = 'baz';
}
```

Comment: @Nick, if you're wondering why your code uses a reference even though your function argument is meant to take an object, prior to php 5 that was actually necessary.

Comment: @rambocoder I'd forgotten about that! Thank goodness for PHP 5.